# How to verify the first link in google search using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have come across a scenario where we have to enter the any text in the search textbox say for example ww enter "Context" in the search text box and then we have to verify the first link in the search page to be "ConTEXT". I am using various verify commands like verifyText, verifyTextPresent, verifyElementPresent. But its showing false when i am runnig using selenium IDE.How could I verify the first link is "ConTEXT"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show what you filled in, in the target field?

Comment: If you want your question answered, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the result element with the `waitForElementPresent`. You can see the full test code at the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.com/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/?gws_rd=ssl</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>ConTEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=gbqfb</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=div.vk_ans &gt; span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=div.vk_ans &gt; span</td>
    <td>con·text</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```